# How to take array members and put them in HTML divs one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array: ["5","4","2"].

How can I put them in DIV elements so that the first DIV will have 5 in it, second 4, third 2 and so on.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = [5,4,1].map(n=>\`<div>${n}</div>\`).join("");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    array.forEach(function(element) {
      var div = document.createElement('div')
      div.innerHTML = String(element)      

      document.body.appendChild(div)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = ["5","4","2"];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    $(".myContainer").append("<div>" + myArray[i] + "</div>");
}
```

Use a for-loop to iterate over the content of the array and use a preferred method to add it to a target. In this case the target is of class `.myContainer`

Answer (score 0):

Use for each loop on array like below.

```js
var array = ["5", "4", "2"];
var html = '';
$.each(array, function(index, value) {
  html += '<div class="txt">' + value + '</div>';
});
$('#masterDiv').html(html);
```

```css
.txt {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='masterDiv'></div>
```